# I allocated and initialize my structures, but cannot free it

Tags: c, malloc, structure, free

I made structures like this

```
// structure of window
typedef struct s_window{
    void        *mlx_ptr;
    void        *win_ptr;
    int         width;
    int         height;
    int         color_floor;
    int         color_ceiling;
    t_map       *map;
    t_key       *key;
    t_player    *player;

}   t_window;
```

And I allocate memory and initializing by this functions

```
int     alloc_window(t_window **window)
{
    (*window) = (t_window *)malloc(sizeof(t_window));
    if (!(*window))
        return (ERROR);
    (*window)->map = (t_map *)malloc(sizeof(t_map));
    (*window)->key = (t_key *)malloc(sizeof(t_key));
    (*window)->player = (t_player *)malloc(sizeof(t_player));
    if (!(*window)->map || !(*window)->key || !(*window)->player)
    {
        free_window(window);
        return (ERROR);
    }
    return(SUCCESS);
}

void    init_window(t_window *window)
{
    window->width = 800;
    window->height = 600;
    window->player->x = 5;
    //window->mlx_ptr = mlx_init();
    //window->win_ptr = mlx_new_window(window->mlx_ptr, window->width, window->height, "cub3d");
}
```

AND I'm trying to free this structures by this functions. I tried both written and commented functions, but both of them do not freeing any structures.

```
/*
void    free_window(t_window *window)
{
    printf ("before freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", window->width, window->height, window->player->x);
    if (window->map)
        free(window->map);
    if (window->key)
        free(window->key);
    if (window->player)
        free(window->player);
    free(window);
    printf ("after freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", window->width, window->height, window->player->x);
}
*/
void    free_window(t_window **window)
{
    printf ("before freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", (*window)->width, (*window)->height, (*window)->player->x);
    if ((*window)->map != NULL)
        free((*window)->map);
    if ((*window)->key != NULL)
        free((*window)->key);
    if ((*window)->player != NULL)
        free((*window)->player);
    free((*window));
    printf ("after freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", (*window)->width, (*window)->height, (*window)->player->x);
}
```

compilier said there's no error and it makes me more confused.

Comment: *nothings work well*. Please clarify what that means. What error or incorrect behaviour are you observing?

Comment: `printf ("after freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", (*window)->width, (*window)->height, (*window)->player->x)` That's obviously wrong. Everything has been freed and accessing freed memory is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kaylum I edited my questions, and I expected segmentation fault errors on `printf ("after freeing... %d, %d, %f\n", (*window)->width, (*window)->height, (*window)->player->x)`, but it printed initialized values.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Accessing freed memory is Undefined Behaviour. UB does not mean it  is guaranteed to seg fault. It may crash, or give wrong values or any other behaviour. It may even appear to "work" some times. The memory is freed - there is no actual way for you to check that but there is no reason to suspect `free` will fail if you pass it a valid unfreed pointer.

Comment: You have: `if (!(*window)->map || !(*window)->key || !(*window)->player) { free_window(window); return (ERROR); }`; you need to use `free(*window)` and add (before that) `free((*window)->map); free((*window)->key); free((*window)->player);` (each of which will either be a valid allocation or a null pointer, both of which are acceptable to `free()`).  You won't spot the mistake with `free(window)` vs `free(*window)` until you actually get a memory allocation failure.

Answer (score 1):

Memory does not get cleared when you free. Reading memory after freeing it is undefined behavior, so don't do that. But provided you pass a valid pointer or a NULL pointer, `free` cannot really fail. Or well, there's no way to test it.

> I expected segmentation fault errors

That's not a correct expectation. It's a possible outcome, but not guaranteed.

Furthermore, I suggest returning a pointer instead of an integer. Returning a NULL pointer for errors is idiomatic. And I suggest removing the casts and using the variable for sizeof. Here is a modified version that properly frees everything upon any failure.

```
t_window *alloc_window(void)
{
    t_window  *window  = malloc(sizeof(*window));

    // Extra variables for readability
    t_map     *map     = malloc(sizeof(*map));
    t_key     *key     = malloc(sizeof(*key));
    t_player  *player  = malloc(sizeof(*player));

    if(!map || !key || !player || !window) {
        // It's ok to free a NULL pointer
        free(map);
        free(key);
        free(player);
        free(window);
        return NULL;
    }

    window->map    = map;
    window->key    = key;
    window->player = player;

    return window;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@klutt 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997767/1752124) explains it already. Just to add -

C language doesn't provide a memory protection mechanism. That means, in context of dynamically-allocated memories, a user can access it using the memory address at any point during execution. Whether a memory address is free or not can not be confirmed by accessing it.

In general terms, `alloc()` and `free()` are not doing any read/write(`reset`) operation to the memory, neither they mark it as valid/invalid. Its only a way of record-keeping to track free memories. When user calls `free()` on a previously-allocated memory, the address just gets added to a list of free addresses. Its user's responsibility to not access invalid or dangling memory addresses after freeing. Thats why its a good practice to mark an address as `NULL` after free-ing it so that you don't read garbage values by mistake.

If you need to verify that your program is allocating/freeing/using memories properly, you can use tools like [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). They are really helpful. In your example, the tool will clearly show that your read access to memory after free is invalid.